# jQuery toggle not working in specific conditions

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm using a simple toggle function to hide-show a div, but 2 problems are arising.

1. How to initially hide a div when page loads and to show(unhide) that div using jQuery on button event.
2. I'm using the toggle function logic on a separate example it's working but not working in this code.

code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#add_button').click(function (){hide_show_add_div();});
});

function hide_show_add_div()
{
                $('#add_new_div').toggle(900);
}
```

add_button is the button id and add_new_div is that div's id which will toggle. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{   
    $('#add_new_div').hide();
    $('#add_button').click(function (){hide_show_add_div();}); 
});

function hide_show_add_div()
{
    $('#add_new_div').toggle(900);
}
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/2fq6d/)

Comment: hey thanks for that demo...but is it necessary to give height as my div height and width are both in %.does it will make any difference because i cant use pixels??and i m getting an error in javascript warning.  '$' is not defined

Comment: no, the height and width are not necessary. it's just an example because my div has nothing in it. [here's another demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/2fq6d/1/)

Comment: `'$' is not defined` means that jQuery was not properly loaded or you're using another library and it conflicted with jQuery.

Comment: hey its now working...i made a very silly mistake..wen including my js-1.4.4.js...i had written <script type="ttext/javascript"> that extra 't' troubled me a lot..thank u ol..

Answer (score 0):

initially hide should work with a style display: none applied to the div

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the div using jQuery code on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#add_new_div').hide();
    $('#add_button').click(function (){hide_show_add_div();});
});

function hide_show_add_div()
{
    $('#add_new_div').toggle(900);
}
```

You could also use CSS to hide it (`style="display: none"`). This has the advantage that the div will be hidden even if javascript is disabled. Hiding it with javascript code may lead to the div appearing for a while and then hiding again. This will happen if javascript runs slow for some reason.